# Why isn't my image in the center when I use Perl::Magick's Extent with Gravity?

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to extent an image a little bit:

```
my $image = Image::Magick->new;
open( IMAGE, $filename );
$image->Read( file => \*IMAGE );
close(IMAGE);

$image->Extent( gravity => 'Center', width => 150, height => 150, );

$image->Write( $outfile );
```

while the the image is extented to the correct size, it is not in the middle.  Am I using this correctly?

Update:

I also tried using the unwieldy version:

```
$image->Set( Gravity => 'Center' );
```

but still no good.  I am using version 6.5.8-10.

2nd Update:

Found this in PerlMagick's changelog:

```
2009-10-18  6.5.7-0 Cristy  <quetzlzacatenango@image...>
  * Interpret gravity properly for ExtentImage().
```

Comment: Your example code works for me with Fedora's Image::Magick package, which seems to be an older version (6.5.4.7).  I haven't managed to build anything newer to compare against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug, as convert outside Perl works.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Ok, you need to extent your image upto 100x100 and fill new area by transparent background:

($nx, $ny) = $image->Get('base-columns','base-rows');
$nnx = 50-$nx/2;
$nny = 50-$ny/2;

$image->Extent(geometry=>"100x100-$nnx-$nny", background=>"graya(0%, 0)");

#woohoo!
```